# Angular trigger after init ResizeObserver - Stack Overflow

Tags: angular

I'm using ResizeObserver with Angular, I init it :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const ro = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        this.headerHeight = document.getElementsByTagName(
          'ion-header'
        )[0].offsetHeight;
        this.containerInfoHeight = document.getElementById(
          'container-info'
        ).offsetHeight;
        if (
          document
            .getElementById('menu-pan')
            .classList.contains('menu-pane-visible')
        ) {
          this.menuWidth = document.getElementById('menu-pan').offsetWidth;
        } else {
          this.menuWidth = 0;
        }
        const { left, top, width, height } = entry.contentRect;
        this.height = height - this.headerHeight - this.containerInfoHeight;
        document.getElementById('canvas').style.height = this.height - 1 + 'px';
        this.width = width - this.menuWidth;
        document.getElementById('canvas').style.width = this.width - 1 + 'px';
      }
    });

    ro.observe(document.body);
  }
```

Code is working.

After init it get width and height when I resize the body.

But I want to run it one time automaticaly after init (without resizing).

I want to get height and width after init without doing anything. Then it will still get updated height and width when I resize the body after the first automatic occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for your problem is to wrap `console.log('ok')` to a function `logOk()` for example, and then call it on `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    const ro = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        this.logOk();
      }
    });

    ro.observe(document.body);
    this.logOk();
  }

 logOk() {
    console.log('ok');
 }
```

Comment: Please see edit that explain why I can't run instructions in the for loop outside the observer. I need height and width.

Comment: You have them :) https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_win_innerheight.asp